# Sequence of connected sets whose limit is disconnected

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let us define $\mathcal{X} = \{0,1\}$.

Is it possible to define a sequence of connected sets $\{ \mathcal{X}_{\nu} \}$, with $\mathcal{X}_{\nu} \subseteq [0,1]$, such that $$\lim_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu} = \mathcal{X}$$ ?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: I've edited the question, I hope it's more clear.

Comment: what about the constant sequence? maybe you can clarify more the question...

Comment: If I connect the title and the body correctly, you're asking whether there is a sequence of connected subsets of $[0,1]$ whose limit is disconnected?

Comment: if so, if you use "standard" definition of "convergence", the answe is no, as connected subsets of the lines are segments.

Comment: @user126154 What do you mean by "constant sequence"?

Comment: @DanielFischer Correct.

Comment: Convergence in what sense?

Comment: @Ita Atz constant means $\chi_\nu=\chi\ \forall \nu$

Comment: @user126154 But $\{0,1\}$ is not constant.

Comment: @Norbert I haven't said anything about convergence. Any type of convergence would be fine though, even epi-convergence.

Comment: From the title I take it that you want the $\chi_\nu$ to be connected?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Yes, I've edited the text to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really specify which type of convergence you have in mind. With the one that I am thinking of, it would follow that $0\in\chi_\nu$ for almost all $\nu$, and the same for $1$. Hence $\{0,1\}\subset\chi_\nu$ for almost all $\nu$, and from connectedness it follows that $\chi_\nu=[0,1]$ for almost all $\nu$, which is a contradiction. Hence, no.

Here I assumed that convergence of a sequence of sets means pointwise convergence of the indicator functions.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I'm a bit confused. What type of convergence are you thinking of?

Besides, consider the following example. The indicator function $I(x)$ can assume only the discrete values {0,1}, whereas the logistic function $L(x,\alpha) \triangleq 1/(1+\exp(−\alphaα x))$ can assume values in [0,1] and $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow + \infty} L(x,\alpha) = I(x)$. Can it be the same for sets?

Comment: Does my clarification help? Did you have another kind of convergence in mind?

Comment: Slightly. I agree with the answer you've proposed, but still the example I gave you above (apparently) contradicts with it. Can you please explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: What is the contradiction? Looking at sequences of sets is the same as only considering functions with values in $\{0,1\}$ (and a sequence in $\{0,1\}$ is convergent iff it is eventually constant).

Comment: Would it be possible then to have $\mathcal{X}_{\nu}=[0,1]$ for all $\nu$ except at the limit, for which $\lim_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu} = \{0,1\}$?